# Enable DDoS protection for GKE Autopilot with Traefik ingress (TCP load balancer)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik-ingress, google-cloud-armor

Has anyone ever configured DDoS protection (with Cloud Armor) for the GKE Autopilot cluster where Traefik is used as an ingress controller. The thing is that Traefik is using TCP load balancer and that is why it is not possible (as far as I can see) to apply Cloud Armor to its configuration. Are there any workarounds for this? Please, share your experience or thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use HTTP(S) load balancer backend services as targets for Cloud Armor.
So, to get the set-up work, you can use Traefik with HTTP(S) load balancer. For more details, refer [here](https://medium.com/@piusnyongesa/up-and-running-with-traefik-v1-7-on-gke-ed8e733ce092)